# Underlay Chart with Detail section

Tags: crystal-reports

My group header has a chart and records in the detail section.

I placed the chart on the left side of the page and the columns of the table (in detail section) to the right. Now i just want them to be side by side. I already tried to set in expert mode the underlay following section in the group header but this will not work. the data source for the chart is a nother than the one for detail section, so Im using suppressing in detail and group.

Answer (score 0):

Take a sub report and place in group header and limit the size of the sub report to the the extent required and don't touch the graph.

Now in sub report place detail data and display

Comment: I am sry forgot to tell: no subreports allowed :)

Comment: In that case I couldn't understand your logic how come you suppress the data at the same Time you want to see the records

Comment: "the data source for the chart is a nother than the one for detail section, so Im using suppressing in detail and group."

Comment: If you need details then you shouldnt supress and if you supress and want to view detail then use sub report that is the only option I can think and suggest